# Change default code highlight in Sphinx documentation

Tags: r, python-sphinx

I'm writing a small R guide with Sphinx.

The default code highlighting language is Python, so I have to add at the beginning of the file `.. highlight:: r` in order to set R as the default code language.

Is there a way to change this option in the `conf.py` file?

I tried to edit `pygments_style = 'sphinx'` but without success..

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to set the `conf.py` var :

```py
highlight_language = 'r'
```

(or 'R' ?)

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-highlight_language

<strike>However I don't see R language support in Pygments language list http://pygments.org/languages/</strike>